# Xamarin dxGrid not updating content

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, devexpress, dxgrid

I'm using dxGrid in a xamarin application to display contents. This works well so far, but I can't get the grid to update values.

I'm using this grid:

```
<dxGrid:GridControl 
    x:Name="grid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding articles, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedDataObject="{Binding selectedRowObject}"
    AutoFilterPanelVisibility="true"
    IsReadOnly="true"
    SortMode="Multiple">
    <dxGrid:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxGrid:TextColumn 
            FieldName="description" 
            Caption = "Description" 
            AutoFilterCondition="Contains"/>
        <dxGrid:TextColumn 
            FieldName="id" 
            Caption = "ID" 
            AutoFilterCondition="Contains"/>
        <dxGrid:TextColumn 
            FieldName="formattedPrice" 
            Caption = "Price" 
            AutoFilterCondition="Contains"/>
    </dxGrid:GridControl.Columns>
</dxGrid:GridControl>
```

In my ViewModel, I use this for the databinding:

```
public List<Article> articles
{
    get
    {
        return dataItem.articles;
    }
}
```

The dataItem object contains a list of articles besides some other general information. When I open the page, the contents show up correctly, but when I'd like to be able to do this manually. For example, this does not work when I'm returning to the oage via `Navigation.PopAsync();`.

To reload the list, I use `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(articles)));`, the pendant of this works for all other elements but the grid. The items of the articles-object are correctly set though when I check them in the debugger, they are just not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick fix that works for me (altough it looks kind of unclean):

In the code-behind of the view:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    grid.RefreshData();
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```